# Extending javascript with keywords

Tags: javascript, language-features, feasibility

My Google-ing on this has been unsuccessful, so here's the question:

I am wondering if it is possible to add my own keywords to extend the JavaScript language in a given framework.

For example

```
Object1 extends Object2
```

in the code would result in executing this method

```
inherit(Object1, Object2)
```

Where inherit is a function that takes care of copying the prototype, adding the parent's constructor, etc..

Is this doable? If so, how ? If not, any other nice way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add keywords to the language but everything is an object and everything can be extended with prototyping.

I wouldn't normally link to crockford but he actually has [quite a decent coverage of this](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html#sugar) , which will afford you syntax of the form `foo.inherits(bar);` which is about as good as one could wish for. This is quite a common pattern.

Comment: Why wouldn't you normally link to crockford?

Comment: Because I disagree with a great many things he says about my beloved javascript, and am of the opinion that his opinions are oft repeated without self consideration.

Comment: @annakata Million times this.  Glad I'm not alone on that opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Several JavaScript macros systems have been developed for this purpose, including sweet.js. Using the [Sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/) macro system, you can replace one keyword with another keyword (for example, replacing the `function` keyword with a `def` keyword.) However, in order to run sweet.js scripts, you must first compile them to JavaScript using the sweet.js compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do like:

```
window.inherit = function(...params){your code here}
```

You can call window's methods without recoursing to window object, so you will be able to call like `inherit(arr1, arr2)`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add new keywords to JavaScript, no. You could create your own nice interface for creating classes though, perhaps drawing inspiration from one of the myriads of library, frameworks and toolkits out there already!

Comment: It actually is possible to create keywords for JavaScript using sweet.js. See my answer on this page. :)